# Facebook Page Feed with Never-Expiring Access Token

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

A client, who's reluctant to give us Facebook credentials, wants us to have a custom Facebook feed on their website.

In the past, it was possible using OpenGraph and just querying for `/user_id/feed/` but now you need to obtain an access token to perform that OG query.

The issue I have is this, we'll need access to their Facebook to create an APP which will allow us to use the OG data, but because they do not want to give us that credentials, I used a Graph Explorer access token which worked fine for 24 hours (up to which point it expired).

Obviously, I don't want the access token to keep expiring, even on a two-monthly basis (the Long-term Access Tokens). How can I just get access to the PUBLIC feed as json format to create a feed with.

Will it be a requirement to create an application and then get them to OAuth approve it to get an Access Token.

I see information about Access Tokens online, but that's for access user's profiles for whoever wants to authorise the APP, however this is just for one client to have on their website.

It would be fantastic to get some information on this that would be simple to implement. I know it used to be until Facebook enforced using an Access Token.

Answer (score 0):

Access token of Facebook users are expire after some hours. If you want to extend Facebook graph API token it can be increased. 
this code will help you to extend user access token

```
$accessToken = $session->getAccessToken();

try {
// Exchange the short-lived token for a long-lived token.
$longLivedAccessToken = $accessToken->extend();
} catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
echo 'Error extending short-lived access token: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
}
```